# Как использовать twig в yii2 для шаблонов писем?

Tags: php, yii2, twig

Пытаюсь настроить yii2, чтобы можно было отправлять письма, используя шаблоны (view) на twig.

Сам twig установлен и работает корректно, странички рендрерит, все хорошо.

Но когда пытаюсь отправить письмо с шаблоном на twig, yii2'шный mailer думает, что это шаблон на php:

```
$number = 123;
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@main/mail/message.html.twig', [
    'number' => $number
])
    ->setFrom('from@domain.com')
    ->setTo('to@domain.com')
    ->setSubject('Message subject')
    ->send();
```

Шаблон `message.html.twig`:

```
Число: {{ number }}
```

На почту шаблон приходит в неизменном виде, без подстановки переменной.

Хотя если сделать просто render:

```
$number = 123;
echo $this->render('@main/mail/message.html.twig', [
    'number' => $number
]);
```

То выводит корректно: `Число: 123`.

Как заставить его распознавать шаблон на twig?

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/mail/BaseMailer.php#L142 Можно попробовать дебагить отсюда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определение view в mailer помогло

```
'mailer'       => [
            'class'            => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'htmlLayout'       => 'layouts/html.twig',
            'view'       => [
                'defaultExtension' => 'twig',
                'class'            => 'yii\web\View',
                'renderers'        => [
                    'twig' => [
                        'class'     => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                        'cachePath' => '@runtime/twig/cache',
                        'options'   => ['auto_reload' => true],
                        'globals'   => [
                            'html' => '\yii\helpers\Html',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
```

Comment: Да, это работает, спасибо. Я ещё обнаружил, что чтобы не дублировать конфигурацию `view`, можно также просто сделать `Yii:$app->mailer->view = Yii::$app->view;` перед работой с `$mailer`.